# When using .get() for an ArrayList, the class doesn't recognize the returned element as object needed

Tags: java

I am trying to return an object from an ArrayList using a for loop and an if statement. Java doesn't seemed to recognize the returned element of the List as the objected that is intended to be returned. Any advice?

```
    import java.util.AbstractList;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class RadioTowerController {


        private AbstractList<RadioTower> alist = new ArrayList<RadioTower>();

        public RadioTowerController(){
            alist.add(null);    
        }

        public void addRadioTower(RadioTower r){
            alist.add(r);
        }

        public void removeRadioTower(RadioTower r){
            for(int i = 0; i < alist.size(); i++){
                if (alist.get(i).equals(r)){
                    alist.set(i, null);
                }
            }
        }
        public RadioTower findTowerforRadio(Radio r){
            for(int i = 0; i < alist.size(); i++){
                if(alist.get(i).covers(r)){
                    return alist.get(i);
                }

            }



        }

    }
```

Comment: The final method, findTowerforRadio, has an error in eclipse, that reads "This method must return a result of type RadioTower.

Comment: You're going to bump into a lot of NullPointerExceptions the way this code is written...

Answer (score 2):

Java compiler want to make sure you the method returns the expected value.
In your scenario, if nothing is found (or the list is empty) the method won't return anything.

You just need to add return statement that would be used in that case:

```
public RadioTower findTowerforRadio(Radio r){
    for(int i = 0; i < alist.size(); i++){
        if(alist.get(i).covers(r)){
            return alist.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here the method returns `null` if nothing is found.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to fix the problem for now :)